# inserting data into database using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, javadb

I have a java Desktop application. 
I am trying to insert data from two text field  in to Database.
But getting some runtime error. 
Help me to resolve it.

Here is my code snippet

```
final String s1 = t1.getText();
final String s2 = t2.getText();
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Details";
        String uName = "rajil";
        String uPass = "rajil";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName,uPass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String q1 = "insert into name (name,id) values('" + s1 + "','" + s2 + "')";
            st.executeQuery(q1);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: and where is an error?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: executeQuery method can not be used for update.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

Comment: there is no syntax error .its runtime

Comment: Don't put stack traces in comments.  Instead, [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20771486/edit)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use below statement also for loading the Drivers classes

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
```

For eg `mysql`

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

See the below link for detail

http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheDerby/article.html

Answer (score 3):

change  `st.executeQuery(q1);` to `st.executeUpdate(q1);`

load drivers first

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
```

Comment: okay .But after getting another error   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'DTS' does not exist.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user3007882 Why are you toggling the Accepted answer ?

Comment: @user3007882 Its your choice.